# How can I delete a Facebook post from my Android app?

Tags: android, facebook

How can I delete a Facebook post from my Android application, using the Facebook Android SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete a Post if your application created the post. Quoting from [Post](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) documentation

> You can delete a post as long as your application created the post. You delete a post by issuing an HTTP DELETE request to the POST_ID object with publish_stream permission.

If the delete is successful, you will get `Boolean` return about the success. And as you want to perform the same on Android you will be required to use [`Request method`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/Request#Request%28Session) and pass `HttpMethod` as `DELETE` to delete the post

Comment: Ya thanks  It there any methods in fb android sdk ,to delete post published by our application ?

Comment: You will be required to use Request method (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/Request#Request(Session, String, Bundle, HttpMethod)) and pass HttpMethod as [DELETE](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/HttpMethod#DELETE) to delete the post

Answer (score 1):

According to Facebook's official documentation, the default HttpMethod is "GET"

package com.facebook
public final class
HttpMethod
extends Enum

Change it to POST or DELETE to post new status or delete them.

Refer [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/HttpMethod#DELETE](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/HttpMethod#DELETE)